# Function of "in making" within " This war is in no ones interest, a disaster in making"

Tags: grammar

Would someone please explain the  grammatical role of the phrase "in making" inside:

> This war is in no one's interest, a disaster **in making**.

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure there is no "the" between "in" and "making"? There should be the definite article, because "in **the** making" is an idiom which means "in development; in the process of developing" ([source](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+making)). So, a disaster in the making is a developing disaster.

"In the making" modifies "a disaster" - (what kind of disaster?) - in the making (developing/being made).

Comment: you might actually be right, I excerpted this sentence from a 
[post](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/05/16/world/middleeast/iran-war-donald-trump.html#commentsContainer) (see top comment under the reader picks section), the omission of the 's' in 'one's' suggest that he might as well have forgot the article 'the'.Apart from this mistake, if it is, are there any instances where 'in making' would have a meaning ,or is it just ungrammatical?

Comment: @Norbert consider the sentence: Bold reforms have succeeded in making our economy more resilient. “In” and “making” appear together in the sentence, and it all makes perfect sense. But this “in making” is a totally diffident story, isn’t it (succeed + in + Ving)? But if I heard “history in making” or “disaster in making,” I’d think of the mistakenly omitted article.